# UNET spawn dynamically generated object unity

Tags: unity, unity-networking, spawning

Spawning works when all clients are connected, but if a client connects after I spawn all my prefabs there are errors.  I spawn the object before changing its Rigidbody's velocity, which seems to cause the problem. I spawn objects, change them, then the other client joins, and the errors come. these are the errors:

```
Failed to spawn server object, assetId=953c1c6ecbb84304280d1334ef5dae0b netId=26
```

I also make changes to variables on other scripts.

All objects have network identities, network transforms, and are spawnable prefabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot use UNET anyways, as it is not performing well. I am going to try DarkRift and see how that goes. it does not seem possible to dynamically generate an object in UNET, in any good way anyways.  I suggest not using UNET for projects with lots of physics and moving objects